# Haskell's read function explanation

Tags: function, haskell, haskell-prelude

I wonder if someone is familiar with the Prelude´s `read` function in Haskell.

The type of this function is following.

```
Read a => String -> a
```

Can someone explain me  with a few examples how this function can be used and into what types the String can be cast?

Comment: I do not quite understand how I can use the function. for example: If I have the String "123", how can I cast it into an Integer ? And more general, can 'a'  be any type (list, integer, pair...), or are their limited possibilities to typecast the String?

Comment: Well the type signature already explains it: it can convert a `String` in any type `a` where `Read a` holds. You can explicitly specify the type, for example `read "123" :: Int`.

Comment: short and clear, thank you @WillemVanOnsem !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Read a => String -> a` means that `a` can be any type that is an instance of the `Read` class. For a type to satisfy that requirement, it has to at the very least have an implementation of either of `Read`'s `readPrec` or `readsPrec` functions. Many built in types aready supply an implementation, and you can use `deriving` to generate an implementation for your own custom `data` types.

To specify what you want to `read` the string as, you can type annotate the call directly:

```
read "1" :: Int
```

Or give the function enclosing the call to `read` a signature so the compiler can figure out what you want:

```
myFunc :: String -> Int
myFunc s = read s
```

The signature says that the function returns an Int, so the compiler can infer what type to `read` `s` as since `myFunc` returns whatever the call to `read` evaluated to.

Comment: Thank you, that was a good explanation. I´ve played around with read now and it become clear to me.